# Prevent checkbox line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I'm making a checkbox drawing program, where the user can draw pictures with checkboxes. I need to disable automatic line breaks on the checkboxes, because they go off the end of the line and mess the square up. For example, here is what happens if I try to draw an 100*100 square:

[image]

Obviously, this is not what I want. How can I disable the automatic line break when the screen runs out of space so the horizontal scroll bar appears?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type = "text/css">
.drawcheck
{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function drawBoxes()
{
var html = "";

for(var i = 0;i<100;i++)
{
   for(var j = 0;j<100;j++)
   {
       html += "<input type = 'checkbox' class = 'drawcheck'>";
   }
   html += "<br />";
}

document.getElementById('drawarea').innerHTML = html;
}

function clearAll()
{
var w = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
for(var i = 0; i < w.length; i++){ 
if(w[i].type=='checkbox'){ 
w[i].checked = false; 
}
}
} 
</script>
<title>Checkbox drawer</title>
</head>
<body onload = "drawBoxes()">
<div id = "controlbar" style = "height:100px;float:top;background-color:#FF0000;"><input type = "button" onclick = "clearAll()" value = "Clear"/></div>
<div id ="drawarea" style = "text-align:center"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On the container add css overflow-x: scroll;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L8eny/   Define a width on the container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`white-space: nowrap` on the container element should do.

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to do instead of using inline-blocks is display block and floating left:

```
.drawcheck {
    float:left;
}
```

You may have to set a width for the checkboxes, though, so that they will clear in the right spots.

Comment: It's going to be very hard to *do* anything with the drawing, if you're not sure how wide each row of boxes is. It's really pretty important that you actually output a series of rows, and know how wide each row is, rather than just outputting one extremely long row and letting word-wrap do its thing.

Comment: There's no reason to set the display type to block if you're using float.